# Search box to search another site

Tags: javascript, html

I've been tasked to replicate the search on http://www.hefce.ac.uk/postcode/
in one of our sites and wondered if it's possible to do this by having a search box in our site and every time a user clicks it will pull the results from the HEFCE site and display on ours, or to simply redirect to the HEFCE site with results?

Many thanks!

Comment: An error has occurred on our Web server is what I get when I tried searching on http://www.hefce.ac.uk/postcode/.

Comment: Hi @KailaashBalachandran Can you try with a postcode like OX1 1BH please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest thing you can do is just use Google CSE and embed it in your site. It's an easy tool where you can just insert the path of the HEFCE site, and it creates the search engine you need.

Comment: Hi Andria,Thanks for your response. I'm not looking to search the HEFCE site for its contents, rather wanting to use their existing postcode lookup on our site. For example, if you search for OX1 1BH in the HEFCE lookup ( http://www.hefce.ac.uk/postcode/) you will get a result and I'm specifically after that functionality.